# Screen Reader message for closing modal

Tags: modal-dialog, popup, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

We have a requirement where we are having hard time implementing.

- User closes modal via "X" or "Cancel" button. The screen reader should tell the user that pop-up is closed and focus is on [X]

Any suggestion around how this can be implemented?

Comment: Using what programming language?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don’t know where your requirements come from, but this seems utter nonsense and actually quite harmful to me. Focus must *never* be on an invisible element, it would even fail one of the most basic [WCAG Success Criteria 2.4.7: Focus Visible](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/focus-visible). When closing a dialog, focus must go outside of the dialog to where it makes sense for the workflow. See the [Dialog pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/dialogmodal/) for more guidance how to do it right. Then you should voice your concern with the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this problem, but here's where I'd start (using JavaScript).

1. Add an [aria-live region](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-live) to your page HTML, and have it [visually hidden](https://accessibility.18f.gov/hidden-content/).
2. Set an onClick event handler on your button. When the event handler is triggered, [close the modal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click), then [post a message to the aria-live region](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) stating that the modal has closed, and finally, [set focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) on the respective element.
3. When it comes to announcing that the focus has moved, you'll again use the aria-live region to post updates. You can either do this as part of the onClick handler (on the button), or you can do it through an onFocus handler on the element that will receive the focus. If the latter, you'll need to make sure that the previous announcements have finished before sending more text to the aria-live region.

Comment: We tried with below code and it's not working for us. Is there any reference code you can share?


  document.getElementById("cancelbtn").addEventListener("click", cancelbtnfunction);

 function cancelbtnfunction(){

                    console.log("test");

                document.getElementById('cancelbtn').setAttribute('aria-label', 'test test test test');

                    document.getElementById("cancelbtn").focus();

                    }

Comment: @Prerit - I added some links to better explain what I'm describing. Hope that's helpful.